# PHP Record Location on Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, geolocation, statistics, ip

I am currently implementing a PHP script that redirects. However, during that redirect I also want to record the user's location. I have tried to do that with the IP-Address and API's of sites such as GeoPlugin, but those are not a free alternative which provide high requests per hour.

So, how would you implement a location-record within a redirection script of php? Thanks in advance!

---

BTW, I am not sure if this is the right forum to post in, please tell me if not and I'll move the post!

Comment: You could always record the IP, and at a later time process the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Maxmind's GeoLite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) Free database if you need only country detection and it fits your needs and licensing. They have native PHP library for fast integration https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php